# custom url in image upload jodit editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-uploading, jodit

I have implemented Jodit Editor (react)https://github.com/jodit/jodit-react, Insert Image option, in which can you upload the image, which saves to the default option by the Editor,

I would like to know how to use custom url and insert the image in editor

Jodit default behaviour

```
config:{

 readonly: false,
        enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,        
        uploader: { url: "https://xdsoft.net/jodit/connector/index.php?action=fileUpload"}

}
```

Expected 
How to do adding custom url

```
config:{

 readonly: false,
        enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,        
        uploader: { url: "www.xyz.com/upload"}

}
```

Comment: You can use dialog /pop up window to ask user for url.

Comment: @Zydnar thanks for reply, after uploading i want to save the image in the custom request url

Comment: @Zydnar  https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/tutorial-uploader-settings.html, I find this but  in react was not working

Comment: React is not that different, but you have to do everything regarding render methods. When you change data - view changes. Don't try to affect components directly with third party libs. I can't help you more precisely without your code.

Answer (score 3):

In this repository, https://github.com/GilianMoa/jodit-editor-react
I'm uploading images with Cloudinary api.
Hope I can help you with this code.

I create a custom buttom:

```
uploadImageButton = () => {
        Jodit.defaultOptions.controls.uploadImage = {
            name: 'Upload image to Cloudinary',
            iconURL: "https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/261-2619141_cage-clipart-victorian-cloud-upload-icon-svg-hd.png",
            exec: (async (editor) => {
                await this.imageUpload(editor);
            })
        };
    }
```

Then I create a method to open a dialog to pick the image and send to a service which send a post with the image file formData to cloudinary.

```
//dialog method
imageUpload = (editor) => {
    
            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
            input.click();
    
            input.onchange = async function () {
    
                const imageFile = input.files[0];
    
                if (!imageFile) {
                    return;
                }
    
                if (!imageFile.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
                    return;
                }
    
                const imageInfo = await FileUpload(imageFile);;
    
                this.insertImage(editor, imageInfo.url);
    
            }.bind(this);
        }

//this method insert the image inside the editor after the upload is done.
        insertImage = (editor, url) => {
            const image = editor.selection.j.createInside.element('img');
            image.setAttribute('src', url);
            editor.selection.insertNode(image);
        }




// this method send the image to cloudinary
    export const FileUpload = async (file) => {
        let result = null;
    
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET}`);
    
        await fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                result = data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use  jodit-react and upload img success ! the code is here hope to help you.

```js
 <JoditEditor
                ref={this.editor}
                value={'this.state.content'}
                config={{
                  language: 'zh_cn',
                  toolbarButtonSize: 'large',
                  uploader: {
                    url: '/manage/upload',  //your upload api url
                    insertImageAsBase64URI: false, not inster base64
                    imagesExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
                    //headers: {"token":`${db.token}`},
                    filesVariableName: function (t) {
                      return 'files[' + t + ']';
                    }, //"files",
                    withCredentials: false,
                    pathVariableName: 'path',
                    format: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    prepareData: function (formdata) {
                      return formdata;
                    },
                    isSuccess: function (e) {
                      debugger;
                      return e.success;
                    },
                    getMessage: function (e) {
                      return void 0 !== e.data.messages && Array.isArray(e.data.messages)
                        ? e.data.messages.join('')
                        : '';
                    },
                    process: function (resp: any) { //success callback transfrom data to defaultHandlerSuccess use.it's up to you.
                      let files = [];
                      files.unshift(resp.data);
                      return {
                        files: resp.data,
                        error: resp.msg,
                        msg: resp.msg,
                      };
                    },
                    error: function (this: any, e: Error) { 
                      this.j.e.fire('errorMessage', e.message, 'error', 4000);
                    },
                    defaultHandlerSuccess: function (this: Uploader, resp: IUploaderData) { // `this` is the editor.
                      const j = this;
                      debugger;
                      if (resp.files && resp.files.length) {
                        const tagName = 'img';
                        resp.files.forEach((filename: string, index: number) => { //edetor insertimg function
                          const elm = j.createInside.element(tagName);
                          elm.setAttribute('src', filename);
                          j.s.insertImage(elm as HTMLImageElement, null, j.o.imageDefaultWidth);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    defaultHandlerError: function (this: any, e) {
                      this.j.e.fire('errorMessage', e.message);
                    },
                    contentType: function (e) {
                      return (
                        (void 0 === this.jodit.ownerWindow.FormData || 'string' == typeof e) &&
                        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                      );
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
```

I have test ok.